# Find high common factor of all possible $n$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

If $n$ is an integer such that $2n + 1$ and $3n + 1$ are square numbers, find the highest common factor of all possible $n$.

Do we need to know exactly what all possible $n$ are?

Answer (score 5):

As $n=40$ gives us the squares $81=9^2$ and $121=11^2$, the desired number $d$ is a divisor of $40$, which limit sour search from above.

As $2n+1$ is an odd square, it os $\equiv 1\pmod 8$, hence $n\equiv 0\pmod 4$. But then $3n+1$ is also odd, hence $\equiv 1\pmod 8$, hence $8\mid n$.
Thus the only remaining possibilities are $d=0$ or $d=40$, and we need to check $n\bmod 5$.

Note that $2$ and $3$ ar enot squares $\bmod 5$.
If $n\equiv 1\pmod 5$, then $2n+1\equiv 3$; if $n\equiv 2\pmod 5$, then $3n+1\equiv 2$; if $n\equiv 3\pmod 5$, then $2n+1\equiv 2$; if $n\equiv 4\pmod 5$, then $3n+1\equiv 3$. It follows that $n\equiv 0\pmod 5$.

We conclude that $d=40$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d$ be the higest common factor of $2n+1$ and $3n+1$. So, we have
$d | (3n+1) - (2n+1) = n$.

But $gcd(n,2n+1) = gcd(n,n+1) = 1$. So $d=1$.

Comment: I would like to find the highest common factor of all possible $n$. Is what you did the same as what I want? Could you please explain?

Comment: But as $2n+1$ is an odd square, $2n+1\equiv1\pmod 8$, so that $4\mid n$. Therefore $d$ is at least $4$.

Comment: ... and then $3n+1$ is also odd, hence $8\mid n$

Comment: Something is wrong here, because you do not use the information that 2n+1 and 3n+1 are squares.